# Laravel Nova 2 models in 1 resource

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

In my case i have a User

```
 Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('address_id')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('address_id')->references('id')->on('addresses');
        $table->string('first_name');
        $table->string('insertion')->nullable();
        $table->string('last_name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('phone_number');
        $table->string('avatar')->nullable();
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
```

And i have a Address

```
Schema::create('addresses', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('city');
        $table->string('street');
        $table->string('zip_code');
        $table->string('state');
        $table->string('house_number');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Is it possible to create a new user and add a address to it in the same Nova User Resource?

What can we add in the fields function of the Resource?

Do i need to overwrite the default create method? Or can this be fixed with a belongsTo ?

Currently i got it to work with using

> morhpOne

method but this is not what i want. I first have to create a User and after that i can add an Address.

Comment: IMO, you've got your relationship backwards. Right now, your users belong to an address. Typically, an address belongs to a user.

Answer (score 1):

This should be simple, in your Nova User model add

```
BelongsTo::make('Address');
```

The `Address` field should represent the function in your `User` model that returns the Address relation

So in your user there should be

```
public function address()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Address::class);
}
```

I hope that that is what you are looking for, I will be happy to update my answer if given more information.

Comment: I already tried this but then i have a dropdown for the addres in my create a user field. When i create a User i want to give it his name, email etc and the Addres, street etc in one go.

Comment: @OhDigiT Ok I get what you are after, not sure if there is i current solution for this. https://github.com/laravel/nova-issues/issues/59

Comment: oke i see. Do you know if I can implement or overwrite the default create, update or save methods? So I can do the database insertion my self?